# Application for simple and quick drawings

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I need you to suggest me an application to make simple and quick drawings.

I need the application to support common image formats and allow me to quickly add text, crop, scale, flip, and rotate.

The tools that I would use would be: pencil, selection, polygons, lines, text, rectangles and circles.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is that you install [Drawing](https://github.com/maoschanz/drawing), it is a drawing application that allows you to make simple and fast drawings.

Although it is open source published under the GNU GPL v3 license, it is not available in the repositories, and requires the addition of a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecartes/+archive/ubuntu/drawing/).

To install it, open a terminal and run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cartes/drawing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install drawing
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, it is just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

A good simple drawing package is [Google Drawings](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=google%20drawings%20tutorial#kpvalbx=_jcvXX5_TMoyxU9inhWA12)

This is a webapp and requires no installation on your Ubuntu system.

just go to https://docs.google.com/drawings to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Kolourpaint](https://apps.kde.org/en/kolourpaint) supports everything you need, and can be installed with just `sudo apt install kolourpaint`